# Is it possible to use media_sideload_image to upload local files in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress, upload, media

I want to add `media_sideload_image` to upload a file programmatically . I've got it working when the image URL is online (e.g. http://etc...) but not when it's a local file from my hardrive or network drive (e.g. file://etc). I get the error `Catchable fatal error: Object of class WP_Error could not be converted to string`.

Is this possible? I'm guessing there must be some way around it as the Wordpress admin site can upload local files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sideloads are used when the media is on another server... you just want a plain upload Try using [media_handle_upload()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/media_handle_upload)

Hope that helps

Regards

Dan